# flutter_image_compress constantly fails on iPad

Tags: flutter, image, dart

`FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile` from `flutter_image_compress` never succeeds to write the output to `targetPath` on any **iPad**.

The exact same code works on **iPhone** and all **Android phone and tablet**.

Here is the function that doesn't run as expected:

```dart
  Future<File?> _compressFile(File file) async {
    final String path =
        '${widget.directoryPath}/users/${User().id}/images/tmp.jpeg';
    final File? result = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
        file.absolute.path, path,
        quality: 50);

    print(result);

    try {
      await result!
          .length(); // from the docs: The returned file may be null. In addition, please decide for yourself whether the file exists.
      print(
          'Compress file from ${(await file.length()) / 1e6} Mb to ${(await result.length()) / 1e6} Mb');
    } catch (e) {
      print('File original size ${(await file.length()) / 1e6} Mb');
      print('Error while compressing file: $e');
      return null;
    }

    return result;
  }
```

On **iPad**, I always have the following output:

```
flutter: File: '/Users/adrkacz/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C2E0A11D-6BC4-47FF-BCAE-A15709073B9B/data/Containers/Data/Application/587B3363-828F-489F-8490-B2099F02D985/Documents/users/a38ededd-5fd5-4639-a303-40c4289cace8/images/tmp.jpeg'
flutter: File original size 1.74672 Mb
flutter: Error while compressing file: PathNotFoundException: Cannot retrieve length of file, path = '/Users/adrkacz/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C2E0A11D-6BC4-47FF-BCAE-A15709073B9B/data/Containers/Data/Application/587B3363-828F-489F-8490-B2099F02D985/Documents/users/a38ededd-5fd5-4639-a303-40c4289cace8/images/tmp.jpeg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

As you can see:

1. `FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile` did not return `null`, it returns a `File` object at the expected location
2. `file` is not an empty file, the program can read its length (**1.74672 Mb**)
3. `result` has no length, which means it doesn't exist, we can confirm that from the output error.

There are multiple problem that could arise:

1. On **iPad** the `directoryPath` is not consistent and should not be used.
2. On **iPad**, the compression algorithm fails to write to the memory.

*Note: `widget.directoryPath` has the value of `(await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path`*

Comment: A theory. The file path you provide is 230 characters long. The maximum file path on iPadOS is 255 characters. Maybe the library is creating a temporary file in the same directory with a long hashed/UUID name to write to and that is pushing the length over the limit, resulting in an IO error that gets silently swallowed. Have you tried running the app through XCode or while the iPad is connected to a Mac and watching the console output?

Comment: Thank you that is a very good insight The first 172 characters are the `directoryPath`, so I cannot optimise much there ..
Unfortunately I don't have a real iPad at hand, just the emulator. I ran the program with Xcode, I got no additional error message.

Comment: Have you tried specifying a shorter path (i.e. remove user id, etc.) as a test?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar problems. The reason was because of the name of the file path exceeding the limits like few have shared in the comments, as a result it's not saving the file successfully hence when you are trying to access the file, it gives the error that no such file / directory . Please make sure your file path is within the limit, that will resolve the issue.